# React js, how to reload the whole component without caching the previous state value in the new rendering

Tags: node.js, reactjs, components

I am implementing a movie search application; in which movies will be returned after clicking search.

In the result lists, user can give "like" to the movies displayed to them.

However, if the user selects to sort by like, the my sort function actually is sorting the "old" search result while some movie's number of like may be changed due to user input.

So, I would like to reload the pages so that the page will go back to the server to load new data and then do the sorting again.

May I know if there is a way to reload the pages by calling my current URL and then I add an extra param on the URL like (sort by no of like). So that I can know I should sort it by no of like in the server-side function

Or if there is a simple approach to deal with this case

---

Edit for better illustration

the search result is a list of movie

**stage 1**

1.
Titanic
like:3

2.
spiderman
like:3

**stage 2** (user give a like to second one)

1.
Titanic
like:3

2.
spiderman
like:4 <----- no of like increased due to the user giving raising point)

**stage 3** User suddenly wants to sort the results by no of like; then I sort the results on the fly.

1.
Titanic
like:3

2.
spiderman
like:3    <------ the results is not updated since the result is old

---

routing function I am using

```
 router.push({
        pathname: "/search",
        query: {sort: sort}
)
```

but the reload is not clean. Component is still cached

### [edit 2]

In each item in the result list, it is actually wrapped by an result card components

So, to sum up, the server passes the search results to the search page.
Then I iterate the results and then return a number of result cards.

In the result card, it allows users to make an action like raise like.
The reason I can keep it dynamic without calling the API is I kept these two hook.

```
const [likeCount, setLikeCount] = useState(movie.likeBy.length);
const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false);
```

But the problem is that when the user clicks the "sort by like", even it gets the new sorted search result. The result card component is still keeping previous data values. It makes the new render weird. That's why I want to make a complete reload that can clear all components' states.

And I found that router.push doesnt do the job

Hope this explains things clear

Answer (score 0):

why do you need to reload the page to get new data you can do it in the same URL
let's assume your baseurl ===>>> "getmovies?sortby="
if you don't pass the value in sortby then it will fetch all data
after adding value in sortby query it will fetch sorted data
sorturl ===>>>"getmovies?sortby=like"

Comment: added a example for why I want it to get the results again from server

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use optimistic UI (which is persistence), I have used it with GraphQL and Facebook uses something similar. As soon as a user likes a movie, React updates the cache which it uses to render the UI. It makes the API call in the background and if it is successful, the UI remains the same (hence optimistic).

Edit:
After you have updated your question, I think we can look into states. Currently you are updating states when user likes a movie but when they sort it again, we are using the old results object or array returned from the server at the first time. If we are not calling the server everytime a user sorts the results, we can store a result copy in a component state fetched from the API and consider it as a source of data for dynamic rendering. Now if a user likes a movie, you update the local state of the result object, it will cause render and updates the UI. When user try to sort the movies, you use local state which has all the latest information and sort it.

Comment: I understand I can use query parameter to tell the url to add a sort. 
But I want a reload with cleaning the page without previous componments state. 

As right now, even I can make a API call to get a new results. 
There is still something weird non-upated data in the page.

Comment: Can you share the piece of code, may be some we can get a better insights?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have edited my answer, see if that helps.